# myActivity extends GridView implements OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, onclicklistener

I'm not sure if the title is ok but i'll try to explain it better.

I want to show a grid in my layout. To do that, i'm using a custom ArrayAdapter. 
I don't how to set the onClickListener to each item...

The layout contains a label, to display a name, and a gridview.

This is my Activity:

```
public class Sala extends Activity{
GridView gridView;
TextView label_name;

ArrayList<String> lista_opciones = new ArrayList<String>();  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_sala);
    //Refresh the name in the label
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    String name= bundle.getString("name");
    label_name= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_name);
    label_name.setText(name);

    //Loading array
    lista_op.add("Op 1");  
    lista_op.add("Op 2");  
    lista_op.add("Op 3");  
    lista_op.add("Op 4"); 

    //AdaptadorOpciones
    ArrayAdapterOpciones mAdapter = new ArrayAdapterOptions(this,lista_op);  

    //Set the customAdapter to the grid
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid); 
    gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);  
}
```

}

Witch methods should I override to implement the onClickListener in each item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

impllement setOnItemClickListener for gridview item click:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_sala);
    //Refresh the name in the label
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    String name= bundle.getString("name");
    label_name= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_name);
    label_name.setText(name);

    //Loading array
    lista_op.add("Op 1");  
    lista_op.add("Op 2");  
    lista_op.add("Op 3");  
    lista_op.add("Op 4"); 

    //AdaptadorOpciones
    ArrayAdapterOpciones mAdapter = new ArrayAdapterOptions(this,lista_op);  

    //Set the customAdapter to the grid
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid); 
    gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);  
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                //Do stuff here
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, it compiles but never runs into inItemClick method.

Comment: If control is not coming in on item click listener then may be you have set clickable as true in your layout. remove clickable from all your view from your layout and then try.

Comment: I've check it but there isn't any clickable attribute set true in my layout_adapter neither in layout_sala (the main one)

Comment: SOLVED: each item was a button (clickable wasn't set true, but is a button). I have put a TextView instead of it and now it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the listener in your Adapter.getView implementation:

```
    @Override       
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView button = (ImageView) convertView;
        if (button == null) {
            button = new ImageButton(); // or whatever
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        button.setId(ids_present.get(position));
        return button;
    }
```